# MKTileOverlay with Retina-Tiles

Tags: ios, mapkit, scale, retina, mktileoverlay

I have issues to load 512x512px tiles in MKMapKit.
The Server provides 512x512 .jpeg tiles.

I could not find any solution or sample implementation for custom retina tiles in MKMapView.

**What I do:**

When I load them into MKMapView with

```
 overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
 overlay.tileSize = CGSizeMake(512.0f, 512.0f);
 [_mapView insertOverlay:overlay atIndex:MAP_OVERLAY_INDEX_TILE level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

… tiles are scaling correct but only half of them is loaded (not only visually - i sniffed the requests and the tiles are missing)

with

```
 overlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
 overlay.tileSize = CGSizeMake(256.0f, 256.0f);
 [_mapView insertOverlay:overlay atIndex:MAP_OVERLAY_INDEX_TILE level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

… all tiles are displayed but scaling incorrect

This is my drawing method:

```
(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayRenderer *overlayRenderer = nil;

    if([overlay isKindOfClass:MKTileOverlay.class])
    {
        overlayRenderer = [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];
    }

    return overlayRenderer;
}
```

… the overlayRenderer.contentScaleFactor is always 1 … no matter what tileSize (iOS simulator 7.1 retina)

**Any suggestions?**

Best regards, Steve

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works only on iOS 7 (not iOS 8).
Override MKTileOverlayRenderer. Tile size is set to 256.

```
@implementation FKDTileOverlayRenderer
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (scale > 1.0)
    {
        CGSize tileSize = ((MKTileOverlay*)self.overlay).tileSize;
        CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGAffineTransform t = CGContextGetCTM(context);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformInvert(t));
        double ratio = tileSize.width/(rect.size.width*2);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, (double)(-rect.origin.x)*ratio, tileSize.height+ratio*(double)rect.origin.y);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, ratio, -ratio);

        [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
    else
        [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
}
@end
```

In your map view controller:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKTileOverlay class]]) 
    {
        return [[FKDTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: And how about iOS 8? Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. This API annoyed me. I have to forget this feeling before I look at it again. Right now I am not displaying retina tiles in iOS 8. There should be a way to provide explicitly both the tile size and the tile scale. I don't see how it can be done differently.